# How to use Splunk CIM Data Model

Tags: eval, splunk

I am trying to understand how to write an Eval statement in Splunk and the documentation isn't helpful. Specifically, I am looking at the Malware CIM Data Model there is a field called "Malware_Attacks" with prescribed values of: critical, high, medium and low. How do I create an eval statement using this CIM Field and the prescribed values and apply it into my regex I created separately in capture groups?

Thanks
Jack

I have tried the Splunk CIM Data Model documentation and it doesn't go into detail on prescribed values and how to apply the CIM Data Field in question on how to incorporate it into writing an eval statement

Comment: There is no `Malware_Attacks` field in the Malware datamodel.  There is a dataset (collection of fields) by that name, however.  The field with values critical, high, medium, and low is `severity`.  What do you mean by "apply it into my regex"?  One usually gets things *out* of a regex rather than into them.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You're correct I misspoke it is the Malware_Attacks CIM Data Model with Severity as the field I am concerned with here. I have to take the prescribed values and create a new field "severity" and apply it into my regex making a calculation with the capturegroups I have already created in my Regex. Does that make sense

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "apply it into my regex".  Can you describe what you want to accomplish with regex?  Perhaps some pseudo-code?

Comment: I dont need to apply it to my regex. trying to create a new field "severity" and use teh prescribed values inside a CIM Data Model. Does this require making a new field extraction or is this done as a field mapping?

Answer (score 0):

The severity field already exists in the datamodel (DM) so all you have to do is reference it.  Do that by specifying the DM name and the field separated by a dot.  For example, `| table "Malware_Attacks.severity"`.  Quotes are used to keep Splunk from treating this as two concatenated fields (since `.` is also the concatention operator).  You can make life a little easier by using `rename` to remove the DM name so fields can be referenced directly.

```
| rename "Malware_Attacks.*" as *
| table severity
```